# How do I reference a model via User model in Django?

Tags: python, django

So I have two models -- `UserInfo` model, which references Django's built-in `User` model, and `Article` model, written by each user, as below.

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    this_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'userinfo', null=True, default=None)
    real_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)

class Article(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'article', null=True, default=None)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
```

And here's part of my `views.py`.

```
def create_ans_us(request):
    current_article = Article.objects.get(id=1)
    ...
    context = {
        'current_article' : current_article,
    }
    return render(request, 'main/main.html', context)
```

And in Django template tag, I'm trying to render the `real_name` field in `UserInfo` like below.

```
<html>
...
{{current_article.user_id.real_name}}
</html>
```

Now obviously, I want to render the `real_name` field to the template. How do I make this possible? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow the `author` of the `current_article`, so:

```
{{ current_article.author.userinfo.real_name }}
```

This will result in an extra database call. You can obtain the data of the author in the *same* query where you fetch the object with [**`.select_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related):

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def create_ans_us(request):
    current_article = get_object_or_404(
        Article.objects.select_related('author', 'author__userinfo'),
        id=1
    )
    …
    context = {
        'current_article' : current_article,
    }
    return render(request, 'main/main.html', context)
```

Comment: Thanks for the kind answer. Does this work the same when I'm fetching more than 1 data? I'm trying to use for loop in my template tag. What other changes should I make in order to fetch multiple objects? (Please ignore the `id` part in query, that was just an example. I'm actually using filter, to get multiple objects.)

Comment: @Ryan: in that case you work with `articles = Article.objects.select_related('author').filter(...)`, pass it to the context with `'articles': articles`, and loop over it in the template with `{% for article in articles %} {{ article.author.real_name }}{% endfor %}`. But I guess if you want a better answer, you should ask a new question with the updated specs.

Comment: Thanks. But for some reason it didn't work, not rendering anything in the template. So I tried `{% for article in articles %} {{article.author}} {% endfor %}`. Then it rendered the `username` of `User` model. Is this normal? I thought it would render the user id.

Comment: @Ryan: does your `author` refers to the `UserInfo` (as in the question), or to the `User` model.

Comment: It refers to `User`.

Comment: @Ryan: then why does the model says it refers to the `UserInfo`?

Comment: Oh I wrote it wrong in the question :( So sorry

Comment: @Ryan: normally you can access the `UserInfo` and render it with: `{{ article.author.userinfo.real_name }}`.

Comment: Oh wow this totally worked. I deeply appreciate it!

Comment: @Ryan: you can boost efficiency further with `select_related('author', 'author__userinfo')` here, since for each `Article` we will eventually need the `UserInfo` object.

Comment: Oh thanks for the additional tip. What would be the difference between the two? (`select_related('author')` vs `select_related('author, 'author__userinfo'`)? I've tried both and what I see in the template doesn't seem different. Both works fine in the same way :)